# Error in C++ code logic

Tags: c++

I am given a graph consisting of N nodes and M edges. A pair of nodes u, v is called good if and only if you can go from node u to v and then return back from v to u without using any edge more than once. I need to add at most one edge to the graph to make all the pairs of nodes good. The added edge can be between two vertices which are already connected by some edges. However you are not allowed to add self loops (edge from node N to node N). It is guaranteed that the graph is connected.

Input
*N and M in first line. Each of the next M lines contains two space separated integers x and y, denoting that there is an edge between node x and y.*

Output
*Output "YES" (without quotes) if it possible to make all pairs of node good by adding at most one edge. Output "NO" (without quotes) otherwise.*

Example`

```
Input:
4 4
3 2
1 3
2 1
1 4
Output:
YES
```

MY LOGIC: I will count all the edges that do not create a cycle that is they simply end. `Eg: Edge(1,4)` in the above example. To do this, I count the instances of a particular node in the input and if it is equal to 1, then that particular node is an end. If we have more than two ends, answer will be "NO".

MY CODE:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n,m,num[100010] = {0},temp1,temp2,i,ctr = 0; //array range is correct
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
    while(M--) //Taking nodes
    {
        scanf("%d%d",&temp1, &temp2); //Node positions inputted
        num[temp1]++; //Counting node instances
        num[temp2]++; //^^
    }
    for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
    {   
        if(num[i] == 1) //If node instances is 1, it is an end node
        ctr++;          //In that case, increment the counter.
    }
    if(N==1 || M==0 || ctr>2)
        printf("NO\n");
    else
        printf("YES\n");
    return 0;
}
```

On submitting this, I get an incorrect answer. Is there a fault in my logic or am I simply missing some testcases?

Comment: Does your code work for the example case?  If not I suggest you step through the code with a debugger and see where your expectations break down.

Comment: It works for that case. My code works fine as such. There are no errors in code

Comment: I did not understand your problem but why not  `if(N==1 || M==0 || ctr>2)
    printf("NO\n");
    else
    printf("YES\n");` instead?

Comment: I can do that, yes. But what is the problem with the code, which testcase doesnt it satisfy?